# Windows 8 wmvcore.dll

Tags: windows-8, windows-media-player, windows-media-center

I am running Windows 8 Pro N x64 without Windows Media Player (which might be called Windows Media Center in the case of Windows 8) preinstalled. Apparently certain software packages require WMP to be installed, in my case Premiere Pro, (wmvcore.dll required error); however, Microsoft will only be releasing it at the end of October, which is a month from now, while no other WMP packages seem to install on Windows 8. Tried downloading a Windows 7 x64 SP1 wmvcore.dll to no avail.

This is a problem for many people at the moment, and a solution would be appreciated.

Comment: Windows Media Player != Media Center.  You can download Windows Media Player by itself, when Windows 8 is released, there is no reason to reinstall the operating system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The N and KN versions of Windows do not include some of the Media-related software and libraries (including WMVcore.dll) by default. The missing software can be found under the name "Media Feature Pack".

[Media Feature Pack for Windows 7 SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=16546)

[Media Feature Pack for Windows 8.1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40744)

You should *never ever* download required system DLL files from unknown sources.

Answer (score 1):

Basically this worked for me "I had issue with Adobe Premiere" and I have Windows 8 Enterprise N.

1. Download a file called wmvcore.dll from this website. http://www.dll-files.com/dllindex/dll-files.shtml?wmvcore "Do NOT click on orange button saying: " download wmvcore.dll fixer" instead click on little grey button at the bottom of the page saying: DOWNLOAD ZIP-FILE!!!
2. Unzip it
3. Copy the file to following folders: C:/windows/system32 and C:/Windows/System32 and also if you have 64bit Windows, copy the file to C:/Windows/sysWOW64

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

To this there is only two solutions at this point that I can determine:

1) Reinstall or upgrade win8 to a non-N version. This will then install all of the appropriate WMP files that you need.

2) Wait for release and see if anyone reverse engineers all the appropriate DLLs and and related files to be stitched in. (This may be a while after release given the low use of "N" products.)

Comment: This answer is pointless, your second option is crazy, no reason to "reverse engineer" anything because you can simply download Windows Media Player come Oct 26

Comment: Not so, I'm under the assumption that he installed the N version of the operating system because he does not want full WMP installed (that is its purpose) once windows releases someone will have to extract the needed system files in order to be able to provide the system resources without the requirement to install WMP as a whole.